# Estoy intentado sacar la media de 3 notas pero la respuesta no me sale correctamente

Tags: javascript

```
    var test = prompt("Enter the first test score.");
    var test1 = prompt("Enter the second test score.");
    var test2 = prompt("Enter the thrird test score.");
    var average = (test + test1 + test2) /3;
    var total = document.write("The average score is " + average);
```

Me sale diferentes respuestas que no son.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

porque estas sumando cadenas de texto aunque sean numeros, tenes que convertirlas a numeros asi:

```
var test = prompt("Enter the first test score.");
var test1 = prompt("Enter the second test score.");
var test2 = prompt("Enter the thrird test score.");
var average = (parseInt(test) + parseInt(test1) + parseInt(test2)) /3;
var total = document.write("The average score is " + average);
```

la funcion parseInt() convierte cualquier cadena de texto que contenga numeros a numeros que puedan ser usados en calculos

Comment: Ok pero también vale poner **Number** atrás del **Prompt**?
**Agradezco mucho tu respuesta**

Comment: var test = Number(prompt("Enter the first test score."));
var test1 = Number(prompt("Enter the second test score."));
var test2 = Number(prompt("Enter the thrird test score."));
var average = (test + test1 + test2) /3;
var total = document.write("The average score is " + average);

Comment: @AlexMorales no pongas código en los comentarios. Mira qué tan fácil se puede leer (o no) lo que pusiste... atmpoco se entiende qué buscas con ese comentario-código

Comment: lo usual es usar parseInt() o parseFloat() (si quieres calculos con decimales).

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias por corregirme recientemente me estoy sumergiendo en este mundo de la programación

Comment: @HernánGarcia Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho

Comment: @AlexMorales lo importante es que entre todos logremos dar respuesta a tu pregunta. Recuerda que si lo que comentó Hernán te resolvió la duda, puedes marcar su respuesta como aceptada con el tick que está a la izquierda, junto a los votos

Answer (score 0):

También puedes hacer que compruebe que es un número lo que estás escribiendo en el prompt. Así no dará ningún tipo de error si metes una letra sin querer:

```
var test = prompt("Enter the first test score.");
    while(!test || isNaN(test)){
        test = prompt("Enter the first test score.")
    }
var test1 = prompt("Enter the second test score.");
    while(!test1 || isNaN(test1)){
        test1 = prompt("Enter the second test score.")
    }
var test2 = prompt("Enter the thrird test score.");
    while(!test2 || isNaN(test2)){
        test2 = prompt("Enter the thrird test score.")
    }

var average = (parseInt(test) + parseInt(test1) + parseInt(test2)) /3;

var total = document.write("The average score is " + parseInt(average));
```

Comment: Gracias, ya que ahorita estoy entrando en el tema de los bucles y condicionales.